# Getting the object of AESDemo() class without using password "test"

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, java-security

Entire code I have pasted just below, please have a look

(1) Out of that code I want to understand this line

```
private static final String password = "test";// I want to remove this line
```

When I am calling this file in servlet what role does this password

```
"test"
```

play in

```
d.encrypt("Hello")??
```

Here is the code:

```
    AESDemo d = new AESDemo();      
    System.out.println("Encrypted string:" + d.encrypt("Hello"));           
    String encryptedText = d.encrypt("Hello");
    System.out.println("Decrypted string:" + d.decrypt(encryptedText));
```

When users will login their passwords can be anything else not "test" so how can I remove this line from the java code, getting error here

```
     spec = new PBEKeySpec(
            // password.toCharArray(),
            saltBytes, // byte[] cannot be converted into char[] I am getting error here 
            pswdIterations,
            keySize
    );
```

(2) When I run the program I am getting encrypted 24 characters, but when I increased

```
new byte[20] to new byte[40]
```

still getting length of 24 characters ,
is it possible to get more encrypted characters like 40 or 50 encrypted characters so that the attacker cannot guess

```
public String generateSalt() {
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
random.nextBytes(bytes);
String s = new String(bytes);
return s;
}
```

Entire code is here:

```
public class AESDemo {

private static final String password = "test";
private static String salt;
private static int pswdIterations = 65536  ;
private static int keySize = 256;
private byte[] ivBytes;

public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {   

    //get salt
    salt = generateSalt();      
    byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");

    // Derive the key
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(
            password.toCharArray(), 
            saltBytes, 
            pswdIterations, 
            keySize
            );

    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

    //encrypt the message
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
    ivBytes = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return new Base64().encodeAsString(encryptedTextBytes);
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws Exception {

    byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new Base64().decodeBase64(encryptedText);

    // Derive the key
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(
            password.toCharArray(), 
            saltBytes, 
            pswdIterations, 
            keySize
            );

    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

    // Decrypt the message
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));


    byte[] decryptedTextBytes = null;
    try {
        decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new String(decryptedTextBytes);
}

public String generateSalt() {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
    random.nextBytes(bytes);
    String s = new String(bytes);
    return s;
}
}
```

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `password_hash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: I am trying the iteration with HMAC but not getting the desired output.. error is coming ..

Comment: Java comes with `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1`, use that. NIST suggests using PBKDF2 for password verification.